# Is it OK to use <div> inside <code>?

Tags: html

Is it OK to use "div" tag inside "code" tag? I am using NetBeans 8.0.1 for writing some html pages. And at some point I had to use "div" inside "code". You can see a part of my code in http://jsfiddle.net/125ypcum/

NetBeans gives me the following error

**Element "div" not allowed as child of element "code" in this context.**

The result is what I want however the error troubles me. Is it a problem in anyway? Is there a way to get the same result without an error?

The code from jsfiddle:

```
<div class="codeDiv">
<pre>
<code class="black">stat<sub>0</sub>;
<div class="back-red codeBoxMargin">if (expr<sub>1</sub>)
<div class="back-green codeBoxMargin">  if (expr<sub>2</sub>)
    {
        stat<sub>1</sub>;
        stat<sub>2</sub>;
    }
    else
<div class="back-blue codeBoxMargin">       if (expr<sub>3</sub>)
        {
            stat<sub>4</sub>;
            stat<sub>5</sub>;
        }
        else
            stat<sub>6</sub>;
</div></div>else
    stat<sub>7</sub>;
</div>stat<sub>8</sub>;</code></pre>
</div>
```

Comment: Use a <span> instead?

Comment: Do you want the semantics of `<code>`? If so, just put `<code>` around your actual code, and nest your divs as you want them.

Comment: @LoweBäckström Using <span> produces a different result. (Background colour only effects the places where texts exist instead of a rectangle as in div) You can try it in jsfiddle.

Comment: @ialarmedalien Using <div> inside pre also gives an error.

Comment: I've put the solution in my answer, but you can get rid of the `<pre>` element and use the css property `white-space` instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to mark up your code with the `code` element, but you want a particular presentation style, use elements like `div` to set the arrangement of the elements, and then `<code>` to mark up the code itself. For your html, this would be:

```
<div class="codeDiv black">
<code>stat<sub>0</sub>;
</code>
<div class="back-red codeBoxMargin">
<code>if (expr<sub>1</sub>)
</code>
<div class="back-green codeBoxMargin">
<code>  if (expr<sub>2</sub>)
    {
        stat<sub>1</sub>;
        stat<sub>2</sub>;
    }
    else
</code>
<div class="back-blue codeBoxMargin">
<code>       if (expr<sub>3</sub>)
        {
            stat<sub>4</sub>;
            stat<sub>5</sub>;
        }
        else
            stat<sub>6</sub>;
</code></div></div><code>else
    stat<sub>7</sub>;
</code>
</div><code>stat<sub>8</sub>;</code>
</div>
```

NB: I have removed the `<pre>` tags!

You can then set the whitespace to be preserved using the css declaration `code { white-space: pre; }` and set your font to an appropriate monospace font.

```
code {
    white-space: pre;
    font: 1em/1.5 Menlo, Consolas, 'DejaVu Sans Mono', Monaco, monospace; /* or whatever */
}
```

[Here's the JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/125ypcum/2/).

`<code>` is an inline element meant for marking up spans of text within block-level elements like `<div>`, `<p>`, and so on. While most browsers will happily render your original html, it would be syntactically incorrect.

Answer (score 4):

`code` is an inline element, while `div` is a block element. Block elements must not appear inside inline elements.

If you want to have a `div` inside a preformatted container, use `pre`. Note, however, that `pre` by default shows line-breaks as-is. Or use a `span` element inside `code` (as proposed by Lowe Bäckström in a comment).

Comment: I tried that however when I use span, background colour only effects the text instead of a rectangle as in div

Comment: In your posted code, why do you need the `code` tag anyway? You've already got the `pre`, right? You can style `pre` with CSS, too. Maybe that's what you're looking for.

Comment: I use "code" just to mention that that part is a code. Since "pre" just tells it is a pre-formatted text. Removing "code" does not change a thing. It is the same error with "pre".

Comment: Ok, wait … then maybe you want a container which *behaves* like a `pre`/`code` element? Then just replace the `pre`/`code` a normal `div` and give it the right CSS rules. Something like `white-space:pre; font-family:monospace`.